# Use dropbox to share azure web apps folder

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, dropbox

In Our Production Web App we have image folder of 34000 images.

We can use azure [Kudu](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/) to zip the Folder, but it's too slow to download large sized folders.

Amazon S3 has option to share web site folder check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbJKgvf8N5o) and [this](http://blog.svnlabs.com/upload-large-files-from-amazon-s3-bucket-to-dropbox-folder/).

Is there option to share web apps folder via dropbox or azure portal ?

Comment: why the down vote ? Let me know to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there option to share web apps folder via dropbox or azure portal ?

As I known, **Amazon S3** is a simple Storage Service provided by Amazon. Based on my understanding, you could leverage [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) to store your images, and you could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to easily work with Azure Storage data.

According to your description, I assume that you are using Azure Web App to host your web application and store images along with your website. Considering that your web application could be scaled to multiple instances, you need to store your files (e.g. image, txt, csv,etc.) to a central data storage. Here are some tutorials for getting started with Azure Storage, you could refer to them:

[storage-getting-started-guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-getting-started-guide)

[storage-how-to-use-blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  Is there option to share azure  blob storage  via dropbox or azure portal ?

Comment: You could manage anonymous read access to your containers and blobs, refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources) for more details. Also, you could leverage SAS to grant limited access to your storage account for other clients, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) for getting started with SAS.

Comment: For a simple way to manage/share your blobs, you could use https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer.md

Comment: ok last question, can i use azure storage explorer to copy blob files to folder in my local machine ? i want to copy 35000 images as fast download to my local machine.

Comment: You could leverage [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) command-line tool with optimal performance to download your images (blobs) to your local machine.

Comment: ok now i can do using blob's. but why azure doesn't provide option share web apps folder to local machine with `AzCopy` ?

Comment: As I known, we could leverage [ftp](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/) or [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to manage web app folder/file. For feature request, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).